# Converter para PDF com php

Tags: php, dompdf

Tenho o seguinte problema, tenho estes valor em html com php (vai buscar os valores ao mysql): 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o meu objetivo seria através da utilização de botões do materialize dava a possibilidade ao utilizador de fazer screenshot ou transformar estes valores em pdf para mais tarde poderem imprimir. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estive a procurar e achei que o melhor seria utilizar para transformar em pdf o dompdf. Aqui vai o código que arranjei:

```
<?php
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
//criar a intancia
 $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$dompdf->load_html(' 
  <h1>Não sei como meter aqui os valores</h1>
');
//renderizar
$dompdf->render();
//exibir pagina
  $dompdf->stream(
    "relatorio_pii.pdf",
    array(
      "Attachment"=> false 
    )
  )
?>
```

E agora o código dos meus botões:

```
<div class="fixed-action-btn click-to-toggle">
      <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">save</i><input type="submit" name="submitpdf" value="Download pdf file" class="input-button"/></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">camera_alt</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">show_chart</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

O problema é que não sei onde meter a formula de php para imprimir e chamar no botão de imprimir. Por favor agradecia imenso a vossa ajuda.